# How to extract nested json object values Python

Tags: python, json

Can someone please help to extract the nested json values.
I have a json structure.
I want to get only value from nested json excluding the key. Do we have any predefined funtcions to use

```
{
 'catalog': [
{
  'catalog_num': 120,
  'type': {
    'screen_inch': 18.0,
    'screen_width': 240.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
  }
},
{
  'catalog_num': 9992,
  'type': {
    'screen_inch': 18.0,
    'screen_width': 36.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
  }
},
{
  'catalog_num': 100,
  'type': {
    'screen_inch': 24.0,
    'screen_width': 576.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
  }
}
 ]
}
```

I want the output in this format:-

```
{
  'catalog': [
{
  'catalog_num': 120,
    'screen_inch': 18.0,
    'screen_width': 240.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
},
{
  'catalog_num': 9992,
    'screen_inch': 18.0,
    'screen_width': 36.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
},
{
  'catalog_num': 100,
    'screen_inch': 24.0,
    'screen_width': 576.0,
    'screen_height': 78.0
}
 ]
 }
```

Is there any way to extract only values from nested json. I want the "type" to get removed from my output and add value to existing object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you're given a dictionary/list structure instead of a json-string (if it's the latter, use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20loads#json.loads)). Then your question basically is

> How do I convert
>
> `d = {   key_1: value_1,   key_2: {key_3: value_3} }`
>
> into
>
> `d = {   key_1: value_1,   key_3: value_3 }` ?

One way to do that would be

```
d.update(d.pop(key_2))
```

Please see the docs of [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for an explanation of `dict.update` and `dict.pop` :)

Now for your use case, you'll just need to repeat that for each of the dictiories in the `'category'` list, probably with a `for` loop.